# hide javascript file in xcode project

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I used javascript in my objective-c/cocoa project.
But after compiling, I found that all script files list in .app content.
Is it possible to hide the scripts or add them to unix executable file?

Welcome any comment

Comment: what do you mean by add them to .app? its already in .app content.

Answer (score 1):

Create hidden javascript file(begins with a dot “.”) and Copy that file in Bundle Resources build phase.

Comment: This will still include the files in the app's Resources folder; Finder just won't list them (unless a hidden preference is set). It'll still be possible to list them, read them, or change them by other means.

Comment: op can also use apple script to execute java script.

Comment: While true, that's incredibly roundabout and unnecessary, and won't solve the problem of hiding the JavaScript code.

Comment: op can execute that script using NSAppleScript.